# How do I create a destructor for my AVL tree?

Tags: c++, class, tree, destructor

I have the code:

```
class Node
{
public:
    ~Node();
    int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    int height;
};


Node::~Node()
{
    delete this->left;
    delete this->right;
    this->left = this->right = NULL;
}
```

I believe that the destructor does not work correctly, without removing "root", help me how to remove my tree completely

Comment: You don't need `this->left = this->right = NULL;`. After this line the `Node` object doesn't exist anymore and member `left` and `right` are gone, too. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: You should initialize your `left` and `right` members to `nullptr` when constructing the object. In return I consider it ill-advised to set the members in the destructor: the object is about to go away and any access to it is undefined behavior either way. You *may* want to set the pointers to an illegal pointer value in a debug build but even that shouldn’t be in the code (the compiler may generate such code). Other than that this code is incomplete as it only represents a node not a tree.

Comment: Prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`. And btw, you don't need those explicit `this->` dereferences. And initialize your members; `Node *left = nullptr;` rather than just `Node *left;` (or use a constructors initialization list if you prefer).

Comment: If you want to delete root node, then why won't you call delete on root node and your destructor already handles recursive deletion of whole tree.

Comment: Use smart pointers: `std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;`. No explicit initialization and no custom destructor needed.

Answer (score 1):

You want the destructor to be in your AVLtree class, not in your Node class.  You should consider making a recursive helper function to do this that will use postorder traversal to delete the tree.

I hope that this is helpful. Here is a very basic example of this:

````
// you will not be needing a destructor for Node because it`s left and right pointers are always going to be nullptr when a Node gets created. You will only need a destructor for Node if you have another resource that you are allocating upon the creation of a Node by using the ```new``` keyword.
struct Node
{
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
};

class AVLtree
{
public:

    Node* root = nullptr;

    void clearTreeHelper(Node*& treeptr)
    {
        if (treeptr != nullptr)
        {
            clearTreeHelper(treeptr->left);
            clearTreeHelper(treeptr->right);
            delete treeptr;
            treeptr = nullptr;
        }
    }

    ~AVLtree()
    {
        clearTreeHelper(root);
        if (root == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Root has been cleared!\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        AVLtree a;
        a.root = new Node;
        a.root->left = new Node;
        a.root->right = new Node;
        a.root->right->left = new Node;
        a.root->right->right = new Node;
    }
}
````